# Why is the colon needed to represent the row but not for the column of a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, row

I've been migrating from Matlab to NumPy/Scipy. There is one fundamental thing I don't clearly understand.

When we have a two-dimensional array like the following:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
```

in order to represent the first column and row, we use the following expressions.

```
col = x[:, 0]
row = x[0, ]
```

So ,we see that : is not needed to represent a row but : is needed for a column.

Could somebody explain what would be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slice notation uses *tuples* to indicate what to slice.

`:, 0` is a tuple with two elements; a `slice(None, None, None)` object (so slicing from start to end with step 1), and the integer 0. The notation `, 0` however is not valid Python. You *have* to have an expression before comma, you can't just leave it blank.

`0,` on the other hand, is a valid tuple. It contains just one element, the integer `0`. Because there is more than one dimension in your array, `numpy` can extrapolate that you wanted to use all elements for the remaining dimensions, so you don't need to give it a `0, :` (== `0, slice(None, None, None)`) tuple.

Answer (score 0):

It is merely because `[,0]` is invalid syntax in Python. Whereas `[0,]` is perfectly legal.

Comment: This is part of the answer, if not all.  `[,0]` does indeed return a `SyntaxError`.  If Python does not allow it, then `numpy.__getitem__` never has the chance to expand it to `(slice(None),0)`.